# How do I get the full hour before the latest in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the second latest full hour. So if the time is 15:30 now, I'm trying to get 14:00, so I basically need to truncate the current minutes and then furthermore truncate an hour..

I'm trying to project the date like this:

```
// Let's say the current time is 15:46
"period": {
    "start": 2022-11-03T14:00:00.000,
    "end": 2022-11-03T15:00:00.000
}
```

It's gonna be something like this:

```
{
   $project: {
        period: {
start: {
  "$subtract": [ {
    $hour: {
      "$toDate": "$$NOW"
    }
  }, 1 ]
},
end: {
  "$subtract": [ {
    $hour: {
      "$toDate": "$$NOW"
    }
  }, 1 ]
},
```

}
}

How do I do that?

Comment: can you add a bit more context? you're trying to use this value in a `find` query? in an aggregation pipeline?

Comment: I'm just trying to make a project at the end of my aggregation and get the period out for the last full hour. So I'm not interested in the current hour, if the time now is 15:40, I'm trying to project "start" as 14:00 and "end" as 15:00, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this one?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
        start: {
          $dateSubtract: {
            startDate: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$$NOW", unit: "hour" } },
            unit: "hour",
            amount: 1
          }
        },
        end: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$$NOW", unit: "hour" } }
  }
])
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood well... But, in case, maybe something like this?

https://mongoplayground.net/p/9xALfPpdSdS

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      hour: {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            $hour: {
              "$toDate": "$period.start"
            }
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

Comment: very close. So there is two issues I see with your code. First one is that it only returns the hour. I want to return the full date not just the hour. Secondly, there should also be an "end" which is basically just the current hour at minute 00. Remember there is no such value as "$period.start", I'm trying to create it, so I can't reference it.